# Matching expression from an input, count matchs and return each entire lignes

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have an input like

"Hey bro

bro its amazing

bazinga"

I used this to count how many time I found occurence

```
    var count = (this.script.match(/bro/g) || []).length;

    console.log('Total: ' + count);
```

It return 2, which is perfect,
But I would like to know if there is a simple way to get the entire line for each matchs. 
So output should be:

Total: 2

Hey bro

bro its amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^.*?bro.*?$/gm` – with multiline (`m`) flag – will match the entire line if an occurence of `bro` is found. Then you just need to return the length of the array for the total amount of occurencies.

```js
var str = `Hey bro
bro is bro amazing
bazinga`;

var rows = (str.match(/^.*?bro.*?$/gm) || []);
console.log(rows);
console.log(rows.length);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot fabrizio ! Little plus, do you know a simple way to know the line when the regex matches ?

Comment: @xif A solution is splitting the string and then check with the regexp every line, but it is computationally expensive.